# TaggedLogger - Log wrapper

Tags: java, android, logging

I wrote this class in order to not having to write `tag` every time (because of *code duplication* and *risk of typos*).

```
public class TaggedLogger {

    public static final TaggedLogger GLOBAL = new TaggedLogger("Global");

    private final String tag;

    public static TaggedLogger forClass(Class<?> someClass) {
        return new TaggedLogger(someClass.getName());
    }

    public TaggedLogger(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public void debug(String message) {
        Log.d(tag, message);
    }

    public void info(String message) {
        Log.i(tag, message);
    }

    public void exception(String message) {
        Log.e(tag, message);
    }

    public void exception(String message, Throwable exception) {
        Log.e(tag, message, exception);
    }

    // skipped

}
```

Using:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final TaggedLogger LOGGER = TaggedLogger.forClass(MainActivity.class);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LOGGER.debug("Initialization: start");
        init(savedInstanceState);
    }

    // skipped

}
```

What do you think? Maybe this class is useless?

Help me choose a more appropriate name for this class (if `TaggedLogger` isn't good) ?

Comment: 1. Apart from simons comments I would like to suggest you that your Constructor **TaggedLogger()** should be private ,So you will force developer to create logger instance via your **static forClass()**  Method    2. Are you using GLOBAL  somewhere else in the code ? if not then you can remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not consider your class useless, I have actually done a similar thing myself. Very similar actually. Perhaps even exactly the same, pretty much.

Overall, your code is very well-written. You use `final` and `private` where you can, which I like.

---

A few comments:

```
private static final TaggedLogger LOGGER = TaggedLogger.forClass(MainActivity.class);
```

Even though it is correct that constants are written in `ALL_CAPS`. One exception for this is loggers. If you write `LOGGER.info` and stuff often, that `LOGGER` will pick on your eyes after a while. I would recommend using the name `logger` (lowercase) instead.

---

```
public static final TaggedLogger GLOBAL = new TaggedLogger("Global");
```

I am not sure if you really need this one. Especially not inside that class.

It is good that you have not made your class a singleton at least, but I'm not sure if this `public static` 'global' is really necessary.

---

I can recommend using [log4j for Android](http://sourceforge.net/projects/log4j-android/) for logging. Log4j is a very nice and popular logging framework for Java, and it is possible to get it working on Android.